# Get NSUserDefaults Nil object

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

The API returns nil value for a parameter and I save this parameter with `UserDefaults.standard.set(userType, forKey: "userType")`. But now how I get this Nil Value ?.

> UserDefaults.standard."?"(forKey: "userType") -> what to do instead of
>   "?"

.

Comment: can you share some more code. Or possibly you can convert it to string before setting it to UserDefault.Or else make a condition

Comment: What will do with more code ? The problem is this .

Comment: Can you please explain a more bit about your question. as i am still not clear what you are asking

Comment: Do you want to check nil on userdefaults return value?

Comment: Absolutely yes.

Comment: check the answer

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL I have made a check condition before and after to check the nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `value(forKey:)` method returns an optional. So you can check like below

```
if let userType =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userType") {
  print("User your value here \(userType)")
} else {
  print("Your value is nil")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly check the nil condition before setting the value to userDefault.

**Before Storing:**

```
if let userType = userType{ //Use here the code from where your are getting data in userType
  UserDefaults.standard.set(userType, forKey: "userType")
}else{
  print("It is nil")
}
```

Be safe before storing it so it never stores the nil value

**After Storing:**

Or If it is save then you can check like

```
        if let userType = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userType"){
            print(userType)
        }else{
            print("nil")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Nil Value using this code -

```
 if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userType") != nil) {
        if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userType") as! String).character.count == 0 {
            //Your value is ""
        }else{
            //some value
        }
    }
```